# Excel vba int conver to double failed

Tags: vba, excel

I want to divide an integer value by a double value, and show a double value result. In the below code, the cell found in column K is an integer, and the conversion to integer fails. How can I fix this?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim value As Double
For i = 9 To 75
  If Range("K" & i) > 0 Then
    value = CDbl(Range("K" & i).Value) / CDbl(Range("M3").Value):
    Range("E" & i).Value = value 
Else
    Range("E" & i).Value = Range("L" & i).Value
End If
Next i
```

Comment: As `Value` is a word used in vba, It should not be used as a variable.  This is not your problem but an observance.

Comment: `value = CDbl(Range("K" & i).Value) \ CDbl(Range("M3").Value):` What's the `:` doing there?

Comment: If you want to divide, use / not \

Comment: Firstly, `:` is used to seperata a block, i tried another name instead of  value, but it did not work.

Comment: Sorry, in normally use /, but I write wrong, when i write here.

Comment: It's confusing to have `:` with nothing following it. Implying something's there when there isn't. Anyways, division sign worked for me.

Comment: Well, result is double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Op mentioned:

> Sorry, in normally use /, but I write wrong, when i write here

That seems to be the reason of the problem see [\ Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264594.aspx)

Replace `\` with `/`

Comment: Are you using Excel or Visual Studio 1015, _read properly they are different_.

Comment: I was wondering why i was getting the correct answer when using 700\100 but 0 when 7\100.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: using excel, what is the different?

Comment: Exactly that you are _using Excel_ no _Visual Studio 2015_